# Why after updating mysql user permissions must the service be restarted?

Tags: java, mysql

My java web project log show that a user does not have the permission to update the database. When I give right to this user, it does not work.

After I restart the program, it successfully updates the table,

Why do I have to restart the project after I update database's user permissions?

Answer (score 3):

execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after change the permissions to reload them

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the user has been granted the permission. Use the following command to check the grants for user:

```
show grants for 'user'@'localhost';
```

And make sure you again use the command : `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after granting the privilege.

Comment: good idea, but the permission must work. they work also after restart

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The permission will work after the restart. Flush Privileges will work.